# How can I dynamically generate types for Redux Actions?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create actions for Redux that correspond with network requests. So, my goal is to have:

```
GET_USERS_STARTED
GET_USERS_COMPLETED
GET_USERS_ERRORED
```

as possible action types. Currently, I can do that with:

```
export type reduxActions = typeof GET_USERS_STARTED | typeof GET_USERS_COMPLETED | typeof GET_USERS_ERRORED;
```

but my goal is to use some dynamic programming so I can do something like:

```
function networkRequestable(str) {
  return [ `${str}_STARTED`, `${str}_COMPLETED`, `${str}_ERRORED`];
}

export type reduxActions = networkRequestable(GET_USERS)
```

And then components, reducers, etc. could rely on the signature of `GET_USERS_STARTED`, etc. without writing out types for every API action that might happen.

I've looked at Interfaces and Custom Guard Checks, but I think Interfaces are too "open" while guard checks are only at runtime to coerce into existing types.

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this or if I'm just thinking about TypeScript incorrectly. Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: I *highly* recommend giving this a look see: https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions

Comment: Thanks for that reference - I've looked at it but am not quite sure how to integrate it with Redux-Thunk, so I'm using some of those patterns but just being explicit. I'm sure I may understand it more as my project continues.

Comment: Here is another repo with lots of examples for react-redux: https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide he uses redux-observable as middleware but here is some discussion about typing redux-thunk: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/213 it can be confusing at first but typesafe react-redux is great, best of luck!